# Android N. Split screen

Tags: java, android, adb

Имеется Android N. Задача: програмно запустить приложение из-под другого приложения в режиме Split screen. Вроде бы как пишут, что через intent и его флаги это реализовать нельзя. Но мне не поверилось и решил все-таки найти какой-либо способ. Вот что пробовал, из более менее похожего:

1. Команда `adb shell input keyevent --longpress KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH`. Не отрабатывает корректным образом. Игнорируется `--longpress`.
2. Команда `adb shell input touchscreen swipe 1200 2500 1201 2501 1000`, где "1200 2500 1201 2501" это координаты x1, y1, x2, y2. Собственно это имитация свайпа на один пиксель, что отрабатывает как long tap. Впринципе расчитать их програмно не проблема совсем. Проблема в том что некоторые девайсы имеют хардверные кнопки, а не отрисованные и также на некоторых APP_SWITCH button находится слева. Поэтому такой вариант тоже отпадает, хотя во многих случаях будет отрабатывать.

Понимаю, что задача не тривиальная, и скорей всего никто не сталкивался. Но хотелось бы услышать ваши предположения по решению.

**UPDATE**: Split screen вызывается longtap-ом по Recents apps button.

Comment: Выставьте на конкурс с 500 очей (типа) - посмотрим сколько будет идей

Comment: @Barmaley Так и планировал сделать, но надо ждать пару деньков

Comment: вы тесты хотите запускать?

Comment: а пробовали капать в сторону accessibility service? там есть такая константа https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN мне кажется это что-то может дать

Comment: @andreich Да, это именно для них. Пробовал, но ничего путнего там не нашел.